# Unable to make Mod_mono in Red Hat even after configure has completed without errors

Tags: linux, apache, mono, redhat, mod-mono

I have successfully run the configure script for mod_mono, but get multiple error messages while making mod_mono in my RHEL 5 server. I ran configure with the following options: ./configure --with-apr-config=/usr/local/bin/apr-1-config --with-apu-config=/usr/local/bin/apu-1-config --with-apxs=/usr/local/bin/apxs --prefix=/usr/local

I have apache 2.4.6 installed along with mono 2.10.2. These are my error messages from make:

```
mod_mono.c: In function âapache_get_useridâ:
mod_mono.c:389: error: âunixd_configâ undeclared (first use in this function)
mod_mono.c:389: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
mod_mono.c:389: error: for each function it appears in.)
mod_mono.c: In function âapache_get_groupidâ:
mod_mono.c:399: error: âunixd_configâ undeclared (first use in this function)
mod_mono.c: In function âapache_get_usernameâ:
mod_mono.c:409: error: âunixd_configâ undeclared (first use in this function)
mod_mono.c: In function âensure_dashboard_initializedâ:
mod_mono.c:488: warning: implicit declaration of function âunixd_set_global_mutex_permsâ
mod_mono.c: In function âconnection_get_remote_portâ:
mod_mono.c:854: warning: implicit declaration of function âapr_sockaddr_port_getâ
mod_mono.c:854: error: âconn_recâ has no member named âremote_addrâ
make[1]: *** [mod_mono_la-mod_mono.lo] Error 1
```

I am totally stuck at this point and have been searching for a solution for days, but to no avail. Any help in this regard would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any help would be much appreciated guys. I'm totally stuck here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my issue. The easiest way is to install monodevelop using yum by following the steps mentioned in the below url :
http://mostlylinux.com/tmp/?p=91